# Keep spans in SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android

Sorry all.  I've never posted here before so I hope I get this right.
I'm trying to work with SpannableStringBuilder.  I want to take them apart, add spans, and put them back together.  I don't think that I can use HTML because I plan to use spans that HTML cannot duplicate. I'm confused because some of the operations are suppose to preserve the spans but, from what I can tell, they are not.  e.g. `s2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(s4);` should copy the spans but is not.

The below is an example of what I need to be able to do.  In the long run I want the final text to be:

[red]**This**[red] is a [red]**Test**[red]
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
// tvHistory is a TextView
// 0         1
// 01234567890123
// This is a Test

final int FLAGS = Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE;
final int COLOR = 0xFFff0000;

SpannableStringBuilder s1 = new SpannableStringBuilder("This");
SpannableStringBuilder s2;
SpannableStringBuilder s3;
SpannableStringBuilder s4;

// works - sets "This" to red
s1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(COLOR), 0, s1.length(), FLAGS);

// works - <red>This<red> is a test
s4 = new SpannableStringBuilder(TextUtils.concat(s1, " is a Test\n"));
tvHistory.append(s4);

// fails - s2 looses the red colored "This"
s2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(s4);
tvHistory.append(s2);

// fails - s1 looses the red colored "This"
s1 = new SpannableStringBuilder(s4, 0, 10);
tvHistory.append(new SpannableStringBuilder(TextUtils.concat(s1, "\n")));

// works - N/A
s3 = new SpannableStringBuilder(s4, 10, s4.length());
tvHistory.append(s3);

// Works - sets "Test" to red
s3.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(COLOR), 0, s3.length(), FLAGS);
tvHistory.append(s3);

// fails - nothing is red
s4 = new SpannableStringBuilder(TextUtils.concat(s1 , s3));
tvHistory.append(s4);

// fails - nothing is red
s4 = new SpannableStringBuilder();
s4.append(s1.append(s3));
tvHistory.append(s4);

// works - both "This" and "Test" are red
s4.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(COLOR), 0, 4, FLAGS);
s4.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(COLOR), 10, 14, FLAGS);
tvHistory.append(s4);
```